# java -version pulling up wrong version

Tags: 14.04, java, jdk

First off I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

I was following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZB3Iy7Lve4&list=PLV1n5wy-eKOybkegVT0Zext93sOm5axPb) to set up a Java JDK and at the end he uses

```
java -version
```

to see his current version number. The Version I installed was 1.8.0_66 but mine returns

```
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.6) (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

But when I check for the JAVA_HOME that seems to be correct

```
user@user:~$ $JAVA_HOME
bash: /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_66: Is a directory
```

Where have I gone wrong? The additional resource he uses in the video is [this](http://p.web.umkc.edu/pv6xc/tutorials.html) and I feel like step 5 is maybe where things are going haywire, even though I do update the file name version before I run the script.

Any ideas? Anything is much appreciated thank you.

After digging around online I ran the line

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

which returned with

```
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_66/bin/java               1         manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

I've tried entering in 1 and sudo 1 etc but the java version doesn't change. And it just redisplays the above code, without changing the default. How do I correctly enter this? If this is even how to do it. According to this I already had java installed in the jvm folder. Is it necessary to use the latest version of java or should I use this preinstalled version? I'm new to java so I'm not very experienced on what I need to be doing.

Comment: Run `sudo update-alternatives --config java` and then enter 1..should do it..

Comment: Try `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_66/bin/java 1100`

Answer (score 1):

heemayl's answer was it.

"Try

```
 sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_66/bin/java 1100
```

"
I did this for the scripts and they went through correctly and java -version now reads the correct one. Thank you!

Comment: my opinion , give chance to @heemayl to post answer =)

Comment: @heemayl I have unmarked my answer if you would like to post yours